# the newly opened pop up window closes itself... how can I stop this?

Tags: javascript

I am practising a simple "window.opener" function with JavaScript and I managed to utilize a function in the parent from the child window.

the function that is called is a simple 'alert('parent alert')' function.

The problem is, when I activate and confirm that the alert('parent alert') function from the newly opened child window, after confirming the alert pop up, **the child window closes itself.**

I have not added any window closing codes so I don't know what I did wrong.

Here's the two html that I made.(it's functional)

parent: https://github.com/kwagjj/mrmine-macro/blob/master/parent.html

child: https://github.com/kwagjj/mrmine-macro/blob/master/child.html

if you want to see it working here's the functional version of parent.html:

https://rawgithub.com/kwagjj/mrmine-macro/master/parent.html

Comment: The second argument passed to [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) _is not_ a title of the new window, it is a name, which is used to refer to the newly created window _in opener_. That name must not contain spaces.

Comment: @Teemu thanks, I didn't know that. I just assumed it would be a title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Parent Window becomes active from the alert, but the Child window is still up. It seems that the Child just went behind the parent and didn't close. At least that is what is happening when I'm using your functional version.